# UITableViewCell autoresizingmask issue

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview, device-orientation, autoresizingmask

I have 3 UI elements in the `contentView` of the `UITableViewCell` that need to be aligned properly when the device rotates. Currently, I enforce the frames of these UI Elements like this:

```
segmentedControl1.frame = CGRectMake(165, 15, 130, 40);
segmentedControl2.frame = CGRectMake(435, 15, 130, 40);
segmentedControl3.frame = CGRectMake(710, 15, 130, 40);
```

I would like to know how I can use the autoresizingMask property of these elements to make them resize and not-overlap on one another when the device is rotated from Landscape to portrait (default is portrait, iPad only). I do not want to have custom frame positions for each orientation.

I tried something like this:

```
segmentedControl1.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin;
segmentedControl2.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin;
segmentedControl3.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin;
```

But this doesn't seem to work. The elements are all overlapped and unhappily laid out.

Any suggestions?

**UPDATE 1**

Here's what the table view cell currently looks like in landscape mode:

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|    ============              ============             ============     |
|   | A   |  B   |            | A   |  B   |           | A   |  B   |    |
|    ============              ============             ============     |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

And here's what I want when the device is rotated to a portrait mode:

```
-------------------------------------------------------
|    ============    ============    ============     |
|   | A   |  B   |  | A   |  B   |  | A   |  B   |    |
|    ============    ============    ============     |
-------------------------------------------------------
```

**UPDATE 2**
Here's my code in cellForRowAtIndexPath incorporating suggestions from @Wolfert

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) 
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    cell.contentView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth;

    // Configure the cell...
    segmentedControl1.frame = CGRectMake(165, 15, 180, 40);
    segmentedControl1.tag = indexPath.row;
    segmentedControl1.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin;
    [cell.contentView addSubview:segmentedControl1];

    segmentedControl2.frame = CGRectMake(435, 15, 180, 40);
    segmentedControl2.tag = indexPath.row;
    segmentedControl2.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin;
    [cell.contentView addSubview:segmentedControl2];

    segmentedControl3.frame = CGRectMake(710, 15, 180, 40);
    segmentedControl3.tag = indexPath.row;
    segmentedControl3.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin;
    [cell.contentView addSubview:segmentedControl3];

    return cell;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

This should do the trick:

```
segmentedControl1.autoresizingMask =   UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin;
segmentedControl2.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin;
segmentedControl3.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin;
```

Note that their super view should have this property:

```
view.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth;
```

Comment: This does not work... sorry! Any more suggetions? I updated the question with some graphics to show what I am talking about...

Comment: Sorry, my fault. I replicated the views to test my solution and it did indeed fail. - I have updated my answer with a working & tested version:)

Comment: Hey @Wolfert, I incorporated your suggestions but it still doesn't seem to work. In fact, with the above autoresizingMask values, segmentedControl2 and segmentedControl3 are disappearing... I updated my question with the actual code I am using.

Comment: I am not sure why this does not work for you. I tested it with UIView's and it worked 100%. Maybe it has to do with your tableview or the segmentcontrols. Sorry that I could not be of any help.

Comment: Thanks @Wolfert! It certainly looks like its a problem with my table view. I'll check it out and see if something can be done.

Answer (score 1):

I am a bit confused that you say you have a working landscape configuration. I would have said that combining your hardcoded `CGRectMake` numbers with the `autoresizingMask` values you cite already result in a skewed layout.

Be that as it may, here is my advice: You should not use hardcoded numbers for the **width** of your initial frames. Instead you should base your calculations on `cell.contentView.bounds.size.width`. In your case, something like this:

```
- (UITableViewCell*) tableView:(UITableView*)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath*)indexPath
{
  static NSString* cellIdentifier = @"Cell";
  UITableViewCell* cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
  if (cell == nil) 
    cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier] autorelease];

  NSArray* items = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"A", @"B", nil];
  UISegmentedControl* segmentedControl1 = [[[UISegmentedControl alloc] initWithItems:items] autorelease];
  UISegmentedControl* segmentedControl2 = [[[UISegmentedControl alloc] initWithItems:items] autorelease];
  UISegmentedControl* segmentedControl3 = [[[UISegmentedControl alloc] initWithItems:items] autorelease];
  [cell.contentView addSubview:segmentedControl1];
  [cell.contentView addSubview:segmentedControl2];
  [cell.contentView addSubview:segmentedControl3];

  // Some values I like
  CGFloat marginHorizontal = 10;
  CGFloat spacingHorizontal = 8;
  // This is the crucial line!
  CGFloat totalWidth = cell.contentView.bounds.size.width;
  // That's how much is available to the three controls 
  CGFloat availableWidth = totalWidth - 2 * marginHorizontal - 2 * spacingHorizontal;
  // That's how much each control gets - initially!
  CGFloat segmentedControlWidth = availableWidth / 3.0;

  // These are the numbers from your example. With these numbers your table view
  // delegate probably implements tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath:()
  CGFloat marginVertical = 15;
  CGFloat segmentedControlHeight = 40;

  CGRect segmentedControlFrame = CGRectMake(marginHorizontal,
                                            marginVertical,
                                            segmentedControlWidth,
                                            segmentedControlHeight);
  segmentedControl1.frame = segmentedControlFrame;
  segmentedControlFrame.origin.x += spacingHorizontal + segmentedControlWidth;
  segmentedControl2.frame = segmentedControlFrame;
  segmentedControlFrame.origin.x += spacingHorizontal + segmentedControlWidth;
  segmentedControl3.frame = segmentedControlFrame;

  // These are the values you cited initially, they are fine
  segmentedControl1.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin;
  segmentedControl2.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin;
  segmentedControl3.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin;

  return cell;
}
```

I tried this on the iPad simulator and it worked just fine. Note that you do not have to change the `autoresizingMask` of either the cell or the content view. I know that this is different from how `UIView` normally works, but I don't have an explanation except that table view cells are strange beasts :-)

Back to your original code: The root problem there is that the hardcoded numbers assume that the content view has the full width of the screen, when in fact its initial width is much less (in my environment `cell.contentView.bounds.size.width` initially is 320). Thus, the initial layout looks something like this:

```
+-content view------------+
|    ============         |    ============             ============ 
|   | A   |  B   |        |   | A   |  B   |           | A   |  B   |
|    ============         |    ============             ============ 
+-------------------------+
```

As you can see, the layout is out of proportion to the initial width of the content view. When the content view is later resized to its correct width, the controls are also resized in proportion to their initial width and horizontal distribution. This causes even more out-of-proportien'ness :-)